# HTML textarea won't autoresize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a `textarea` and attached [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) to it so that it would autosize properly when a newline is created. Initially the `textarea` is supposed to take up 100% of the height of its container. Here is the code:

```
#editor {
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important; 
  resize: vertical;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

And the js code:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
     autosize($('#editor'));
   });
</script>
```

Ideally I would like the `textarea` to grow by one row everytime a newline is created or there is a word wrap. Is there a better solution?

EDIT: The problem is that the `textarea` is not growing at all.

Comment: "*I would like the `textarea` to grow by one row*": what's happening instead?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that shows your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `height` css rule. Traditionally, when you set the height of a `textarea`, you use the `rows` attribute directly on the `textarea`. e.g:

```
<textarea id="editor" rows="4"></textarea>
```

If you remove the `height` property from your css rule it should resize as you input text.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/h079m7nz/1/)**

Comment: Yes this was the solution!